# How I can Call Custom perl Module in java

Tags: java, perl

I have tried with inline:java to call perl module in java . But it give error **"No instance of InlineJavaServer has been created!"**

Basiclly i need to call our custom perl module in java code. Please  help me, send me manual how i setup the things .

Thanks In advance

Comment: Inline::Java is used to use a Java class from inside a Perl program, not the other way around.

Comment: So  can you please tell me how i can call perl in java . Currently i am using Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("perl C:\\testpm.pm model"); is there any other  ways to use .

Answer (score 0):

See the page here: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2004/jw-1011-xmlrpc.html